# F# Interleave 2 lists

Tags: list, f#

Is there a way that I could merge 2 lists

```
let a = ["a"; "b"; "c"]
let b = ["d"; "b"; "a"]
```

so I get this result

```
result = ["a"; "d"; "b"; "b"; "c"; "a"]
```

Comment: were you trying to find the solution yourself?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A quick & dirty solution would be to zip the two list, then flatten the resulting tuples:

```
let interleave a b =
    List.zip a b |> List.collect (fun (a,b)-> [a;b])
```

This returns a list with the interleaved elements:

```
interleave a b;;
val it : string list = ["a"; "d"; "b"; "b"; "c"; "a"]
```

`zip` will create pairs from the elements of both lists :

```
val it : (string * string) list = [("a", "d"); ("b", "b"); ("c", "a")]
```

and `collect` will flatten the tuples

Answer (score 8):

This task is best solved by `foldBack2`:

```
let al = ["a"; "b"; "c"]
let bl = ["d"; "b"; "a"]

List.foldBack2 (fun a b xs -> a :: b :: xs) al bl []
// ["a"; "d"; "b"; "b"; "c"; "a"]
```

Answer (score 3):

To complement @Panagiotis Kanavos's standard library-based answer, here's a hand implementation which should consume slightly less memory because it doesn't build tuples (but still requires an intermediate list):

```
let interleave a b =
    let rec loop acc a b =
        match a, b with
        | [], l | l, [] -> List.rev l @ acc
        // Or if you want to fail when the lengths are different, replace the above with:
        // | [], [] -> acc
        // | [], _ | _, [] -> failwith "interleave: List lengths are different"
        | a :: aa, b :: bb -> loop (b :: a :: acc) aa bb
    loop [] a b |> List.rev
```

(The solutions in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9090799/merge-two-lists) are not tail-recursive, so sub-optimal too)