# Why List.foldBack is implemented via mutable Array (and not via continuation)?

Tags: f#, f#-powerpack

I've been reading [F# core library sources](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsyme/archive/2010/11/04/announcing-the-f-compiler-library-source-code-drop.aspx) (v.2.0) and found something rather interesting:
`List.foldBack` is implemented via a mutable Array, unlike `List.fold` which is pretty straightforward. Here's the source or you may find it [here](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/89263e0df38789efa141766cea4c27f244bd368b/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/list.fs):

```ml
let foldArraySubRight (f:OptimizedClosures.FSharpFunc<'T,_,_>) (arr: 'T[]) start fin acc = 
    let mutable state = acc
    for i = fin downto start do
        state <- f.Invoke(arr.[i], state)
    state

// this version doesn't causes stack overflow - it uses a private stack 
let foldBack<'T,'State> f (list:'T list) (acc:'State) = 
    // skipped optimized implementations for known lists

    // It is faster to allocate and iterate an array than to create all those 
    // highly nested stacks.  It also means we won't get stack overflows here. 
    let arr = toArray list
    let arrn = arr.Length
    foldArraySubRight f arr 0 (arrn - 1) acc
```

**What is the reason not to use continuation?**
Something naive like the code below seems to work only 2-3 times slower than the highly optimized library method. It seems questionable that it is really *"faster to allocate and iterate an array"*. Also, it is tail recursive, so no StackOverflow here.
Am I missing something?

```ml
let foldBack2 predicate acc list =
    let rec loop list cont =
        match list with
        | [] -> cont acc
        | h::t -> loop t (fun racc -> cont (predicate h racc))
    loop list id
```

Comment: "2-3 times slower...seems questionable that it is really 'faster to allocate and iterate an array'". You just found that it is 2-3x faster.

Comment: @JonHarrop Skipped `...` stands for **than the highly optimized library method**. Wrap `predicate` into `OptimizedClosures.FSharpFunc`, make optimized `match` items for lists of size 1,2,3, and 4, build the whole thing with carefully chosen compiler options and you will barely see any difference.

Comment: "the highly optimized...you will barely see any difference". I'd challenge these assumptions. Just inlining the standard library function can make it 5x faster so it obviously isn't "highly optimized". If you use CPS then you're allocating lots of unnecessary objects and, if they survive the nursery, that will certainly be much slower than the array-based solution.

Comment: Also, benchmarking your solution on this 2.3GHz Intel Core i7-3610QM it is 8x slower than `List.foldBack` and not 2-3x as you claim. In fact, even making your changes it is still nowhere near as fast as the standard library function.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I can think of a few reasons not to use CPS:

1. you trade memory for stack space (all those continuations live on the heap)
2. CPS is inscrutable to most people
3. as you discovered, it's generally slower than the alternatives (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7199122/162396) for evidence)

A list can't be easily traversed backward and since arrays can't be beat for sequential access (forward *or* backward) copying to/from an array is actually pretty efficient. As a challenge, try writing a faster `foldBack` for 10,000/100,000/100,000,000 elements.

Answer (score 5):

[Make the common case fast](http://www.cs.iastate.edu/~prabhu/Tutorial/CACHE/common_case.html).

In practice, you often deal with small lists which do not cause stack overflow anyway. As an example, the counterpart of F#'s `List.foldBack` in OCaml, [List.fold_right](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/List.html), isn't tail-recursive or using CPS either.

As users, we don't really care what is the internal implementation. We enjoy the surprise of having both fast and tail-recursive `List.foldBack`. For instance, this beautiful [split](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7945580/634025) function is tail-recursive in F#:

```
let split list = List.foldBack (fun x (l,r) -> x::r, l) list ([],[])
```