# How to stop the traversal of a list

Tags: f#

I start in Fsharp and I have this question.
Assuming I have two lists a and b of the same length, I travel theses lists simultaneously and test a condition on a and b each step, with the result of a previous calculus. If this test fails there is no need to keep on.
I wrote this code :

```
let mutable (i : int) = 0
let mutable (good : bool) = true
let mutable (previous : int) = 0
while good && i < len do
    good <- test a.[i] b.[i] previous
    previous <- my_func a.[i] b.[i]
    i <- i + 1
```

I saw this code which is much much better :

```
List.zip a b |> List.fold (fun (x, y) (a,b) -> (p && test a b y, my_func a b) (true, 0)
```

But, with my code, as soon as the test fails, the process finished, not with the second code.
Is there a way, using the design of the second code to stop the process ?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you are only interested in whether the final result is `good`.

As mentioned by Brian, you can use `Seq.scan` which behaves like `Seq.fold` but it returns all the intermediate states rather than just the final state. By using `Seq` instead of `List` you are also using a lazy sequence and so functions can terminate early. To do what you want, you can use `Seq.scan` together with `Seq.forall`, which will check that all values of a given sequence satisfy a certain condition - the nice thing here is that this can terminate early as soon as the condition is `false`.

Putting all this together, I get something like this:

```
Seq.zip a b 
|> Seq.scan (fun (good, prev) (a, b) -> 
     test a b prev, my_func a b) (true, 0)
|> Seq.forall (fun (good, _) -> good)
```

Comment: I like this, and it turned out simpler than I anticipated. You could even simplify the last line to `|> Seq.forall fst`.

Answer (score 1):

Three ideas:

- You could write your own variation of `fold` that stops when a flag is set to false. Personally, I think that would be cumbersome, though.
- You could use `Seq.scan` to lazily accumulate all the results of `my_func` and then examine them, similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23098746/344223). Since `Seq` is lazy, the scan would short circuit the way you want. This is tricky to get right, though.
- You could walk the lists recursively. IMHO, this is the simplest functional solution. Something like this:

```
let rec examine listA listB prev =
    match listA, listB with
        | headA :: tailA, headB :: tailB ->
            if test headA headB prev then
                let prev' = my_func headA headB
                examine tailA tailB prev'
            else false
        | [], [] -> true
        | _ -> false
examine listA listB 0
```

Comment: Thank you for your answe and the link. Basically your code has the same design as my own code, but it's much more elegant !